# Using AutoHotKey to remap Ctrl to Alt while retaining Alt+Tab as Task View hotkey

Tags: windows, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

I am a long (long) time Mac user, who has recently begun working in a company that uses Windows. I am using AutoHotKey to remap the Alt key to Ctrl, to mimic the placement of Mac's cmd key. The issue is, I would also like to retain the use of Alt+Tab to quickly switch between open windows, and I cannot figure out how to do so, even after reading the AutoHotKey docs.

Importantly, I do not have Admin privileges, so cannot use other software like PowerToys. Does anyone know the correct structure of an .ahk file to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
; remap the Alt key to Ctrl
; and the Ctrl key to Alt:

Alt::Ctrl
Ctrl::Alt


; retain the use of Alt+Tab:

^Tab:: ; ^ is the symbol for Ctrl
    Send {Alt down}{Tab}
    KeyWait, Ctrl ; wait for Ctrl to be released
    Send {Ctrl up}{Alt up}
return
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).